# warning: unable to access '/home/gitolite/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied

Tags: git

I finished setting up git-daemon for read access to some of my git repositories, however, when client does pull, it gets this:

```
remote: warning: unable to access '/home/gitolite/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
remote: Enumerating objects: 18, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (18/18), 4.68 KiB | 2.34 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
```

Everything seems to work fine, but I cannot figure out the warning and how to get rid of it. The git-daemon is running under gitolite user. That user does have home and the file exists and is readable.

```
$ sudo -u gitolite -- ls -l /home/gitolite/.config/git/attributes
-rw------- 1 gitolite gitolite 0 Mar 16 22:42 /home/gitolite/.config/git/attributes
$ sudo -u gitolite -- cat /home/gitolite/.config/git/attributes
```

```
+   $ ps u 13243
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
gitolite 13243  0.0  0.0   9864   980 ?        Ss   22:42   0:00 /usr/lib/git-core/git-daemon -
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check the permissions of the parent directories.

Comment: When I run `cat` as the user `gitolite` it can read the file..